# Driving 3 2K monitors over Displayport 2.1 MST

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a three monitor setup utilizing DP MST, with each monitor able to support up to 1440p resolution. I was originally running an AMD Radeon 5700XT GPU, which supports DP 1.4. and while the monitors worked fine, the third one was limited to 1080P due to bandwidth constraints.

I recently upgraded to an AMD Radeon 7900XTX, which happens to support DP 2.1. I was under the impression that driving all three monitors at 1440p would be feasible now, however I failed to account for the DP protocol supported by the monitors themselves, which is 1.4. Thus, while I can still run all three monitors, the last one is stuck at 1080p.

While I can run an additional cable from the GPU, my wiring setup is a little unorthodox due to the design of the office, so it would be a hassle to do (the current DP cable run about 45 feet from the computer to the first monitor).

As far as I'm aware, there's practically zero productivity monitors on the market that offer DP 2.1 with MST support. I'm wondering if there is another solution that I may not be aware of, besides just biting the bullet and running an additional cable.